# If I only serve gzipped version of my content, should I add the vary accept encoding header?

Tags: http-headers, static-content, gzip, amazon-s3

I just moved a static site from a VPS to Amazon S3. I have decided to serve only gzipped version of my pages, since S3 is not a webserver I can't have logic based on headers. I also use Cloudfront as CDN.

I was testing my page with http://gtmetrix.com/ and got a bad note because I don't add the `vary accept encoding header`. So I checked what this is about and as far as I understand it makes sense when we serve both compressed and uncompressed versions.

So I'd like you to help me clarify this. Should I add it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have decided to serve only gzipped version of my pages

If you're only serving files that you've compressed using *gzip*, then using `Vary: Accept-Encoding` will be of no benefit since there won't be uncompressed copies of the files to serve to clients that don't send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the [HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). Most clients these days do send this, so you should be fine.

Online website performance tests don't know that you're only serving compressed files, and they're also not fool-proof either. You might note for example that the service you used lists these under a column labeled `RECOMMENDATION`, so it's wise to follow-up any suggestions like this with some fact-finding (like you did) before becoming too concerned or trying to implement them.

Comment: I just want to add, that my doubts came from this post: https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/accept-encoding-its-vary-important/

Comment: You're fine. That article discusses using `Vary: Accept-Encoding` on the origin server with a CDN. As you indicated, your origin server doesn't provide this, and it's really no longer necessary since according to Google [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression): `All modern browsers support and automatically negotiate gzip compression for all HTTP requests.` Therefore they recommend using _gzip_ on all sites. That article (from 2/2013) just states: `These days you're unlikely to have clients without compression, but why risk cache mixups?`...

Comment: Since you're serving only _compressed_ files though, "cache mixups" (i.e., from uncompressed versions of the same files) wouldn't apply to your situation.